# ImageViews not rendered when after changing/reloading/rotating fragment

Tags: java, android

I have encountered a weird bug in my fragment class: imageViews "disappear" if I rotate/reload the view. From my understanding, rotating/reloading destroys the View and re-creates it, so local variables and local view elements may not preserve. However, I have made a manual button that should manually render the images again after I click it, yet the ImageViews stay gone even if I manually reset their imageResource or imageBackground resource. Note that these imageviews are animated-drawables. Below is most of my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mView = rootView;  //mView is global
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("gnereed id", "id is "+R.id.generate_button);
    final Button generate_button = getView().findViewById(R.id.generate_button);

    if ( bottleMap == null ) bottleMap = new Hashtable();


    // the code sets all images to invisible onCreate
    // their visibility will be changed when a bottle is "created" 
    ImageView[] bottles = new ImageView[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < bottleAry.length; i++){
        bottles[i] = getView().findViewById(bottleAry[i]);
        bottles[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    

    // this is a button that generates a new bottle and manually refreshes all previous bottle
    // If fragment has not been reloaded/rotated then everything works here
    // after fragment reloads, new bottles can be generated but old bottles do not re-render.
    generate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bottle bottle = new Bottle("123", bottleList.size());
            bottle.setVisible();
            bottleList.add(bottle);
            Log.e(" mView : ", mView.toString());

            // for all bottles created, re-render them
            for (int i = 0; i < bottleList.size(); i ++) {
                bottleList.get(i).reRender();
            }
        }
    });
}

public class Bottle{

    String message;
    ImageView bottleLocation;
    int imageSrc;
    int avail_index;
    int bottle_index;
    int locationID;
    AnimationDrawable bottleAnimation;

    public Bottle(String msg, int bottle_index){
        message = msg;
        this.bottle_index = bottle_index;
        locationID = getRandomBottleLocation();
        bottleLocation =  getView().findViewById(locationID);
        Log.e(" old View : ", getView().toString());

        // sets the image source and sets visible, lastly start animation
        imageSrc = getRandomBottleImg();
        bottleLocation.setBackgroundResource(imageSrc);
        bottleMap.put(Integer.toString(locationID), imageSrc);
        bottleAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) bottleLocation.getBackground();
        bottleAnimation.start();

        bottleLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ViewBottleActivity.class));
                availableLocation[avail_index] = false;
                bottleMap.remove(Integer.toString(locationID));
                bottleAnimation.stop();
                bottleLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                bottleList.remove(bottle_index);
             }
        });

    }

    public int getRandomBottleImg(){
        int bottle;
        Random rand = new Random();

        bottle = imgAry[rand.nextInt(imgAry.length)];
        return bottle;
    }

    public int getRandomBottleLocation(){
        int location;

        Random rand = new Random();
        avail_index = rand.nextInt(bottleAry.length);
        while (availableLocation[avail_index]){
            avail_index = rand.nextInt(bottleAry.length);
        }

        location = bottleAry[avail_index];
        availableLocation[avail_index] = true;

        return location;
    }

    public void reRender(){
        Log.e("location ID is:" , Integer.toString(this.locationID));
        bottleLocation =  mView.findViewById(this.locationID);
        Log.e("ImageView is:" , bottleLocation.toString());
        imageSrc = getRandomBottleImg();
        bottleLocation.setBackgroundResource(imageSrc);
        bottleAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) bottleLocation.getBackground();
        bottleAnimation.stop();
        bottleAnimation.start();
        this.setVisible();
    }

    public void setVisible(){
        bottleLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: add generate_button.performClick(); on onResume(); in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. What I learned is that you cannot use

```
View.findViewByID(viewID)
```

outside of onViewCreated(). Notice how I implemented reRender() function inside the onViewCreated() but it didn't work? The result is that mView.findViewByID(viewID) is actually executed OUTSIDE OF onViewCreated() although I call the function from WITHIN.

Yes, the line will be executed, but upon inspection,  mView.findViewByID(viewID) will return TWO DIFFERENT objects when called from inside onViewCreated() and when called from a function that is called from onViewCreated().

This is very counterintuitive, especially for us who's taught to deploy the DRY(do not repeat urself) principle. The fix is just to simply not write outside functions for handling View.